# Not able to see the API button on the Fauxton of CouchDB

Tags: api, couchdb, couchdb-futon, couchdb-2.0

Hi I´m not able to see the API button on the fauxton of cocuhDB, do you know why it´s this.

Answer (score 1):

In recent releases of Fauxton (the web-based dashboard for Apache CouchDB), the "API" button, which links to the API equivalent of the page you are looking at, has been renamed with a `{} JSON` label.

[image: Apache Couchdb Fauxton screenshot]

Comment: The button doesn't display properly - please see my answer for a picture

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually an answer, but in response to @Glynn Bird the button doesn't display properly:

[image]

It's on a 21" (non-HD) monitor.